# Using MPI reduceAll with custom operation function

Tags: c, mpi

I am trying to gain an understanding as to the usage of the reduceAll MPI function.

In my main project, I have an array of numbers, with each process processing part of the array, and then having each process after, communicate their result, which forms the new array for the program to repeat.

So for this basic example, I simply have an array of size 2503, and have each MPI process store some hard coded numbers at different positions in the array. Then after the reduceAll to have an array of size 2503, but the value in the last location [2502], would have changed from what was initially put in.

```
#include <mpi.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void stitchResultArrays(double *in, double *inout, int *len){
    printf("0= %f\n", in[0]);
    printf("out1= %f\n", inout[0]);
    printf("out1= %f\n", inout[1]);
    printf("1= %f\n", in[1]);
    printf("len = %d\n", *len);

    inout[2502] += in[2502];
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);

    // Get the number of processes
    int world_size;
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &world_size);
    int arraySize = 50;

    double sendMpiMessage[2503];
    double test[2503];

    // Get the rank of the process
    int world_rank;
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &world_rank);

    printf("size = %d\n", (arraySize * arraySize) + 3);
    sendMpiMessage[2502]= 4.1;
    sendMpiMessage[2501] = 4.4;
    sendMpiMessage[2500] = 4.2;

    sendMpiMessage[0] = 4.5;
    sendMpiMessage[1] = (double) (world_rank + 5);

    MPI_Op stitchResultArraysOp;
    MPI_Op_create((MPI_User_function *)stitchResultArrays, 1, &stitchResultArraysOp);

    printf("------");
    MPI_Allreduce(sendMpiMessage, test, 2503, MPI_DOUBLE, stitchResultArraysOp, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    printf("result = %f\n", test[2502]);

    MPI_Finalize();

    return 0;
}
```

In this example, I would assume the length inside the reduceAll function to be of size 2503, (same as the array sizes), however it would seem that the *len is 1251 in one process and 1252 in the other process and am not sure why this would be the case?

As a result, it would seem my action of:

```
inout[2502] += in[2502];
```

Causes a segfault, presumably for trying to access something larger than the array size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your initial assumption is incorrect.

Under the hood, MPI might use various optimization techniques that lead to shorter messages and reductions on subarrays.

A possible fix is to use a derived datatype (e.g. a vector of 2503 `MPI_DOUBLE`), update your user defined reduction and then `MPI_Allgather()` with `count=1`.

Answer (score 3):

`MPI_Allreduce` is defined to operate in parallel (conceptually, not in the sense of concurrency) on the various elements of the array.  That user-defined operations have a `len` parameter is for efficiency (fewer calls through function pointers and possible vectorization), and as you see the implementation can subdivide the array into blocks of whatever convenient size.  (In this case it was probably limited by the buffer size used for communication.)

As [Gilles said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48123252/8586227), you’ll have to make your own datatype to force the array to be treated as a unit.

Comment: Yes, this is the key idea - there's an important difference between performing a reduction on 2503 doubles and performing a reduction on a single object which happens to contain 2503 doubles.